# Getting error while importing PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "access_log" (
    "id" BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nextval(''access_log_id_seq''::regclass)',
    "user_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "platform" SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "device_id" VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "location" VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "ip" VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "access_log_user_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "public"."users" ("id") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

[image]
I am trying to restore my PostgreSQL using HeidiSQL. It is showing **invalid input syntax for type bigint**.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the sequence is at the end of it's range

Comment: By the way, you have the wrong type for your created and updated columns. Should be `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Why would a timestamp be the wrong datatype?

Comment: Too many quotes ' in your statement, nextval() is a function and not a piece of text.

Comment: Unrelated, but: an IP address should be stored in a column defined as `inet` . Btw: there is no magic optimization when using 255 as the length limit for a varchar compared to e.g. `260` or 274`

Comment: @FrankHeikens Because `TIMESTAMP` cannot track a moment, a specific point on the time line. That type lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. So we don’t know if noon on the 23rd of January 2023 means noon in Tokyo, noon in Toulouse, or noon in Toledo — three different moments, several hours apart.

Comment: @BasilBourque: And what about a situation where all data is located in a single timezone? My main DC is in Amsterdam and everything is connected to CET, even in the case we would move the DC to a different tz. What would be the benefit of a time zone?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Moments should generally be stored with an offset of zero hour-minutes-seconds from UTC, "in UTC". This is the behavior of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in Postgres: Any time zone or offset provided with an input is used to adjust to UTC (an offset of zero). Likewise, such values are retrieved from the database in UTC (offset of zero). The app should then adjust to a particular time zone as expected by the user or as demanded by business logic. But we are on a tangent from the Question here. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. I and others have posted on this topic extensively.

Answer (score 1):

The call of the `nextval()` function must not be quoted.

So this:

```
default 'nextval(''access_log_id_seq''::regclass)'
```

needs to be:

```
default nextval('access_log_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Comment: I used this default nextval('access_log_id_seq'::regclass) but still not working.

Comment: @KapilDevSingh: "sill not working" is not  a valid Postgres error message. The CREATE TABLE [will work just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/zoSizXRV) if the sequence (and the table `users`) are created.